# Como melhorar a velocidade de gravação de arquivo para um ClientDataSet?

Tags: delphi, desempenho, arquivo, importação, tclientdataset

Estou fazendo a integração de um sistema com um arquivo bancário, e estou tendo um problema no processo. Recebo da operadora de cartão de crédito um arquivo de texto puro com aproximadamente 1300Kb e cerca de 5.500 linhas.

Estou fazendo a leitura deste arquivo e armazenando em um `ClientDataSet`, apenas em memória, não insiro no banco de dados em momento algum. No entanto estou achando que o processo de leitura está muito lento, uma vez que estou conseguindo gravar a uma taxa de cerca de apenas 13 linhas por segundo, não tenho muito experiência com `ClientDataSet` e não sei se está taxa está aceitável.

Para ler o arquivo eu importo o arquivo de texto para uma `StringList`, em seguida faço um loop com base na quantidade de linhas do arquivo, importando cada tipo de registro para o seu respectivo `ClientDataSet` (Dentro do arquivo podem ter 9 tipos de registros diferentes, e cada um coloco em um `ClientDataSet` diferente).

Loop no arquivo:

```
  EnableDisableControls(False);
  { Percorre todas as linhas do arquivo verificando o tipo e executando uma rotina para cada tipo de registro. }
  for I := 0 to (Extrato.Count - 1) do
  begin
    CurrentLine := I;
    case StrToInt(Copy(Extrato.Strings[I], 01, 01)) of
      0: LerHeader;
      1: LerRegistroDetalheRO;     //Resumo de Operação
      2: LerRegistroDetalheCV;     //Comprovante de Venda
      3: LerRegistroDetalheIDROSA; //Informativo detalhe do RO do Saldo em Aberto
      4: LerRegistroDetalheIBSA;   //Informativo por bandeira do Saldo em Aberto
      5: LerRegistroDetalheIOAR;   //Informativo de Operação de Antecipação de Recebíveis
      6: LerRegistroDetalheIRODA;  //Informações de RO da data antecipada
      7: LerRegistroDetalheIDRODA; //Informações de débitos de ROs da data antecipada
      9: LerTrailer;
    end;
  end;

  { Reativar todos os controles após a inserção. }
  EnableDisableControls(True);
```

Caso o registro seja do tipo 2, por exemplo, chamo a respectiva procedure de gravação no `ClientDataSet`:

```
procedure ThreadProcessarExtrato.LerRegistroDetalheCV;
begin
  with FrmExtratoEletronicoCielo, Extrato, DSDetalheCV.DataSet do
  begin
    Insert;
    FieldByName('TIPO_REGISTRO').AsString := Copy(Strings[CurrentLine], 001, 1);
    FieldByName('ESTAB_SUBMISSOR').AsString := Copy(Strings[CurrentLine], 002, 10);
    FieldByName('NUMERO_RO').AsString := Copy(Strings[CurrentLine], 012, 7);
    FieldByName('NUMERO_CARTAO').AsString := Copy(Strings[CurrentLine], 019, 19);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //Aqui existem muitos outros campos que são atribuídos, retirei para ficar menor...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Post;
    Inc(TotalRegistrosCV);
  end;
end;
```

Então, alguma idéia de como agilizar este processo? Ou uma maneira melhor de realizar este processo?

Comment: @Tiago não sei se não entendi sua abordagem, mas eu recebo texto puro da operadora de cartão de crédito, os registros são delimitados apenas de acordo com a posição dos caracteres, sendo assim acredito que não seja possível utilizar o XML Mapper.

Comment: Pensei que era XML. Talvez trabalhar com `Append` ao invés de `Insert` seja mais rápido. Você pode efetuar vários `Append´s` e só dar `Post` no final. Ainda, fora isso, você pode tentar diminuir a quantidade de uso de `FieldByName`.

Comment: Trabalhar com `TextFile` eu acredito que seja mais rápido.

Comment: Vou fazer alguns testes tentando estas alternativas @Tiago.

Comment: Arthur estou fazendo a mesma integração estou com problema em conciliar as informações de um registro com outro
ex: no arquivo vem os registros
0 - header
1 - Detalhe do RO
2 - Detalhe do CV
9 - Trailer
tem algum campo que vc usou para integrar as duas operações do arquivo
campo que contenha na tipo de registro 1 e 2 do arquivo para casar as informações.

Comment: @KleberTrindade Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Mas pelo que entendi você quer saber como vinculei os campos do Resumo de Operação (RO) com Comprovante de Venda (CV). Caso seja isso mesmo, eu criei um relacionamento master-detail entre os dois registros usando o campo Numero Unico do RO (no RO) e os 22 primeiros dígitos do campo Número Único da Transação (no CV). Isso para o arquivo de Pagamento com CV, que é um dos dois tipos de arquivo que implementei.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Olá,
já tive que fazer algo parecido, fica algumas sugestões que melhoraram bastante o desempenho no meu caso.

1 - Altere a propriedade `LogChanges` do ClientDataSet para `False` (isso diminui bastante o tempo de inserts em massa)

2 - Se você não está exibindo os dados do ClientDataSet em algum controle visual execute `ClienteDataset.DisableControls` antes de iniciar os inserts

3 -Se o ClienteDataset não estiver indexado, de preferência pelo uso do `Insert` ao invés do `Append`, pois o Append tem que posicionar no fim do dataset o novo registro inserido

4 - Se você tem muitos campos no Dataset eliminar o uso do `FieldByName` pode ajudar bastante também. Se os fields já estão criados no dataset em tempo de design você pode acessar ele diretamente pelo objeto `TField` (exemplo: `ClienteDataset1NOME.AsString`)

5 - O ClientDataSet não é bom para inserção de muitos registros, se ele estiver indexado a curva na operação de muitos inserções é exponencial, isso pode ser evidenciado por meio da ferramenta ASMProfiler. Uma opção que ajuda na performance é a eliminação dos índices antes de iniciar essas operações em lote e restaurar os índices no final da operação assim o custo fica mais linear.

Comment: Já estou procedendo com os testes, assim que terminar aviso o resultado. :)

Comment: +1 por "eliminar o uso do `FieldByName`" e usar `DisableControls`.

Comment: Sobre o `Insert` ser mais rápido que o `Append`, não sabia, pensava o contrário. Só sei que `Append` adiciona no final. Adicionei +1 tb! ;)

Comment: O DisableControls já estou utilizando, se verificar o início do primeiro trecho de código verá uma procedure chamada "EnableDisableControls" onde desabilito os controls de todos os ClientDataSets utilizados. Uma dúvida é, acessar diretamente o campo (ClientDataSetCAMPO1.AsString) é tão rápido quando utilizar o Fields[X]? Me indicaram o índice, mas como tenho o CDS criado em design time, posso utilizar assim.

Comment: Sobre qual é o mais rápido, não sei. Só para incrementar a discusão sobre `Append` e `Insert`: [delphi-insert-vs-append-performance](http://jdmullin.blogspot.com.br/2008/08/delphi-insert-vs-append-performance.html), que fala sobre o `Insert` ser mais rápido.

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade, Acessar o campo diretamente ou via índice possui uma diferença desprezível. Mas normalmente código fica mais claro acessando diretamente. Só que nem sempre é possível.

Comment: Referente a diferença de desempenho do uso de `ClientDataSetCAMPO1` ou `Fields[X]` não há diferença, pois no segundo caso você está acessando diretamente pelo índice, com isso ele não precisa percorrer os fields. Utilize o que ficar melhor para você.

Comment: Para remover o uso do FieldByName sem perder a legibilidade e sem utilizar datasets criados em designtime do código você pode: 1 - Criar um objeto e nele uma property para cada field e associar no afteropen  ou 2 - Criar variáveis locais e associar o field pelo indice apenas 1 vez

Answer (score 6):

Não conheço os detalhes do seu sistema, mas 780 linhas de um arquivo texto por minuto me parece baixo, a não ser que você esteja puxando o arquivo de algum lugar da rede.

Pelo que vi, todos os comentários até agora focaram no `clientdataset`. Acho válido mudar um pouco o foco.

Para arquivos *"pequenos"*, utilizar uma `StringList` para ler o arquivo txt é muito válido. Geralmente é mais rápido, mais fácil, parece perfeito.

Mas o fato é: Utilizando `StringList`, você traz para a memória o seu arquivo texto. Pelo que entendi, o arquivo que você está utilizando é enorme, e em casos como este, percebi que utilizando a estrutura de arquivo, não trazendo todo o txt para a memória, as coisas fluem melhor.

Testei em um arquivo com 500.000 linhas (Entrada.txt).

Testei primeiro a `StringList`: **(nem preciso dizer que não rolou, né?)**
[image: StringList]

Logo depois utilizando a forma que propus:
[image: IO]

---

### Segue exemplo para teste:

Você normalmente chama a função desta forma:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  arquivo : Tstringlist;
  I: Integer;
  linha : string;
begin
  arquivo := TStringList.Create;
  arquivo.LoadFromFile('c:\Entrada.txt');
  for I := 0 to arquivo.Count - 1 do
  begin
    linha := arquivo.Strings[i];
    . . . (tratamento da linha)
  end;
  showmessage('pronto');
  arquivo.Destroy;
end;
```

Teste fazendo desta forma:

```
var
   arquivo : TextFile;
   linha   : string;
begin
  AssignFile(arquivo,'c:\Entrada.txt');
  Reset(arquivo);
  while not eof(arquivo) do
  begin
    readln(arquivo,linha);
    . . . (tratamento da linha)
  end;
  showmessage('pronto');
  CloseFile(arquivo);
```

Não sei se isso vai resolver a sua lentidão, mas talvez consumir menos memória ajude um pouco.

Answer (score 1):

Para abertura de um arquivo texto prefiro abordagem direta, assim o arquivo é liberado logo após sua leitura:

```
  function StreamToString(Arquivo: String): String;
  var
    oMemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
  begin
    Result := '';
    if FileExists(Arquivo) then
    begin
      oMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        oMemoryStream.LoadFromFile(Arquivo);
        SetString(Result, PChar(oMemoryStream.memory), oMemoryStream.Size);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(oMemoryStream);
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Quanto ao DataSet ele realmente é necessário?
Na minha visão utilizamos apenas para efeito estético neste caso, o que pode ser substituído pelo controle de byte e não de linha.
Transferindo o conteúdo do arquivo para uma variável e desta variável diretamente para o banco seu processo deve ter um ganho considerável.
Trabalhando com arquivos de 200mb com dados de um cartão de credito fiz as quebras e executava o COMMIT a cada 10.000 registro em uma base Oracle e gravava algo entorno de 60 registro por segundo.
Exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TDados = record
    Nome  : String;
    Obs   : String;
  end;

var
  rDados    : TDados;
  sTexto    : String;
  sAuxiliar : String;
  nCount,
  nIndex    : Integer;
  nCommit   : Integer;

  function Grava(Dados: TDados): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := True;
    // processo de gravação
  end;

  function Commit: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := True;
    // processo de COMMIT
  end;

  function StreamToString(Arquivo: String): String;
  var
    oMemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
  begin
    Result := '';
    if FileExists(Arquivo) then
    begin
      oMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        oMemoryStream.LoadFromFile(Arquivo);
        SetString(Result, PChar(oMemoryStream.memory), oMemoryStream.Size);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(oMemoryStream);
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin

  sTexto := StreamToString('C:\Arquivo.csv');
  if Trim(sTexto) = EmptyStr then
  begin
    Raise Exception.Create('Arquivo vazio!');
  end
  else
  begin
    for nCount := 1 to Length(sTexto) do
    begin
      if (sTexto[nCount] in [#10, #13]) and (sAuxiliar <> '') then
      begin
        rDados.Obs := sAuxiliar;
        sAuxiliar  := '';
        Grava(rDados);
        if nCommit < 10000 then // Vai depender do banco de dados
          nCommit := nCommit + 1
        else
        begin
          Commit;
          nCommit := 0;
        end;
      end
      else if (sTexto[nCount] = ';') then
      begin
        nIndex := nIndex + 1;
        case nIndex of
          0 : rDados.Nome := sAuxiliar;
          // demais campos com exceção do ultimo;
        end;
        sAuxiliar := '';
      end
      else if not (sTexto[nCount] in [#10, #13]) then
        sAuxiliar := sAuxiliar + sTexto[nCount];
    end;
  end;
end;
```