# Como melhorar o desempenho da consulta do clientdataset com muitos registros?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Quando estou buscando todos os registro da tabela clientes, que são muitos, de um banco remoto e exibindo em um DBGrid, este processo leva muito tempo.

Como eu faço para melhorar o desempenho da consulta do clientdataset quando são retornados muitos registros?

Comment: Talvez as respostas [desta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11498/6454) ajude em algo.

Comment: cara não ajudo não, mas vlw!

Answer (score 3):

Use a propriedade `PacketRecords` para determinar quantos registros dever ser retornados em cada pacote pelo provider.

Desta forma os dados serão retornados rapidamente mas a informação toda vai demorar mais a ser retornada e ser exibida gradativamente

A propriedade se comporta de forma diferente, dependendo do seu valor:

- **-1:** Retorna todos os registros
- **0:** Retorna apenas os metadados
- **>0:** Retorna a quantidade de registros informadas a cada solicitação ao provider

#### Exemplo

```
ClientDataSet1.FetchOnDemand :=True;  
ClientDataSet1.PacketRecords := 100;
```

Para mais informações, [consulte aqui no site da Embarcadero](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet_PacketRecords.html)

Answer (score 0):

a melhor forma seria otimizar o comando SQL, colocando o menor numero possível de junções (left ou inner join).

Em resumo buscando boas praticas de programação e comandos SQL.

Caso queira realizar uma consulta perante o comando já informado no ClientDataSer a forma mais rapida seria utilizar a opção filter

```
clientDataSet.filtered := False;
clientDataSet.filte    := '';
clientDataSet.filter   := 'Condição';
clientDataSet.filtered := True;
```

Com esse método o clientDataSet não realiza uma nova consulta somente filtra os registros que estão armazenados nele mesmo