# Como otimizar a consulta em um banco remoto utilizando ClientDataset?

Tags: sql, delphi, otimização

Estou utilizando um *ClientDataSet* para consulta em um banco remoto, a tabela possui mais de 100 mil registos e esta ficando muito lento, a SQL que estou utilizando é:

```
select (coalesce (cast(A.con_baixa as date),current_date) - cast(A.con_vencto as date) )Diastraso,
        A.CLI_CODIGO, A.CON_DOCUMENTO, A.CON_PARCELA, A.CON_DOC_ORIGEM,cast(A.CON_LANCTO as date) CON_LANCTO,
        cast(A.CON_VENCTO as date)CON_VENCTO, A.CON_VALOR, A.PLA_CODIGO, A.CON_TIPO, A.CON_PREVISAO,  A.CON_ESPECIE,
        cast(A.CON_BAIXA as date)CON_BAIXA,A.CON_PAGO, (A.CON_JUROS + A.CON_MULTA) CON_JUROSMULTA, A.CON_SITUACAO,
        A.BANCO, A.AGENCIA, A.CONTA, A.CONTA_R, A.CHEQUE, A.EMITENTE, A.CIDADE, A.CLI_REPASSE_CODIGO, A.CLI_REPASSE_NOME,
        A.CON_VL_BRUTO, A.CON_ID, A.BOL_CONTA, A.BOL_NOSSONUMERO, A.BOL_LINHADIGITAVEL, A.BOL_LOTE, A.NOSSONUMERO,
        A.CON_HISTORICO, A.IDORDEMSERVICO, A.ECF_NUMERO,  A.STATUSCONTA, A.CON_FPAGTOID, A.CONTRATOLOC, A.CON_DESCONTO,
        A.CON_OUTROS, A.IDLOTE, A.IDPAI, A.MOVORIGEM, A.IDCARTAO, A.CON_DATA, A.IDBORDERO, A.CCUSTOID, A.IDDESCONTO,
        A.IDLOJA,B.cli_nome, C.PLA_DESCRICAO, D.DESCRICAO CENTROCUSTO, E.FDESCRICAO, NomeFantasia
from contas A
left join CLIENTES B on (B.cli_codigo = A.cli_codigo)
left join PLANOCONTAS C on A.PLA_CODIGO = C.PLA_CODIGO
left join CCUSTO D on A.CCUSTOID = D.CCUSTOID
left join FPAGTO E on A.CON_FPAGTOID = E.FPAGTOID
inner join Loja F on F.IdLoja = A.IdLoja
where  (A.CON_LANCTO >='03/05/2013 00:00:00' and A.CON_LANCTO <= '03/24/2015 23:59:59' )
        and A.CON_TIPO = 'R' and A.IdLoja in (1) and A.STATUSCONTA <> 'AGRUPAMENTO'
        order by A.IdLoja, A.CON_LANCTO
```

Comment: Vamos lá ? qual SGBD ? As tabelas tem índice ? As estatísticas estão atualizadas ? Foi feito o Plano de Execução da query ?

Comment: Qual a necessidade de carregar todos os registros?

Comment: estou utilizando o firebird, não tem indice, estatisticas não estão atualizadas e não foi feito nenhum plano, sou novato e não sei como funciona...

Comment: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-set.html#isql-set-plan

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54034/como-melhorar-o-desempenho-da-consulta-do-clientdataset-com-muitos-registros

Answer (score 1):

Você conseguiu identificar se o que está lento é a execução da query ou o carregamento no dataset ? quantos registros estão retornando na consulta, pelo que entendi, provavelmente o problema é que muitos registros estão sendo retornados, e como sabemos o clientdataset coloca todos em memória.

Criar índices para **alguns** campos pode ajudar muito, porém não adianta sair criando um monte de índices, isso pode prejudicar a performance. É necessário analisar o plano de consulta para avaliar os melhores índices para serem criados.

Answer (score 0):

[Utilize a propriedade `PacketRecords` para carregar seu `TClientDataSet` incrementalmente](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet_PacketRecords.html).

Por experiência, 500 é um bom valor. -1 serve para trazer um único bloco (seu caso) e 0 traz apenas metadados sobre a consulta em questão.

Evite usar valores mais altos que 5000. Fazendo isto, você estará transferindo o gargalo de memória para a consulta em banco.

Answer (score 0):

Se não tem nenhum índice está fazendo full scan table e esse é o motivo da demora. Crie índices para cada campo no Join e no Where e rode a query novamente

Comment: Os campos que estão nos joins são chave primaria, já possuem um index criado para cada um deles e mesmo assim fica lento

Comment: E os campos do Where ?  Esses também precisam de índices

Comment: Não tinha vistos o Order by, esses se não tem, tem que ter índices também

Comment: eu criei para todos do where e order by, mesmo assim continua a mesma coisa ;s

Comment: Bom agora que seu banco está cheio de índices e a culpa não pode ser imposta a ele, o problema é a quantidade de registros trazidas de uma só vez para o client, faz a sugestão do Cigano Morrison mendez que postou uma resposta limitando a quantidade de registros trazidos por vez